# Understanding two points on top of each other after ModelBuilder intersect?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, coincident

A model I'm making is creating two points on top of each other after intersecting a grid (fishnet). There's only 2 lines crossing each other at these points, so the output should only have one point.

Any ideas why it would be throwing 2 points?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic boils down to:

- Line A is crossed by line B at point 1
- Line B is crossed by line A at point 2

In other words, there's a point for each line where it's intersected by another line.

Just use the Delete Identical tool or something similar if this is an issue.

Comment: Aaaah, that makes sense. Since it's an intersect on one feature, it accounts for every line in that feature. Thanks.